# tuples to dictionary with two occurances

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

My question is how to turn two tuples in a dictionary, and have it so that if there are two strings that are the same in the first tuple, it returns the first element from the second tuple:

e.g.

```
def tuples_to_dict(x,y):
    mydict= {}
    
    for k,v in zip(x,y):
        mydict[k]=v
    return mydict

tuples_to_dict(('a','b', 'c', 'a'), (1,2,3,4))
```

however this outputs:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

However I would like it to be:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Apologies if this is too simple a question to be stuck on! I know I have to add more to my code which is why its returning the wrong output I want, I've had a look at other resources however it doesnt answer my specific question. I've thought about putting an `if` statement and do `x.count(k)>=1:` However I didnt know where to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

Just one extra check needed to see whether the key is already in the dictionary.

```
def tuples_to_dict(x,y):
    mydict= {}
    
    for k,v in zip(x,y):
        if k not in mydict:
            mydict[k]=v
    return mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the element in reversed order would achieve what you need:

```
def tuples_to_dict(x, y):
    return dict(reversed(list(zip(x, y))))

tuples_to_dict(('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Ideally you should check that the two lists have the same length, to avoid unexpected results: `zip` will truncate to the shortest list by default.

There could be a debate if reversing *before* or *after* zipping, but I think the latter is better for the following reason - if you pass list of different lengths:

```
x = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a') 
y = (1, 2, 3)

dict(reversed(list(zip(x, y))))

dict(zip(reversed(x), reversed(y)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}  # This is more in line with what I would expect
{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

In Python 3.10 you can force `zip` to throw an exception in case the zipped lists have different lengths (passing `strict=True`), and that would avoid any issue in this respect.

Comment: This is much more complete than mine +1. Also I think since they are sequence types, `len()` can be helpful if we don't want to iterate over all the items first, that is what  `strict=True` does. For huge items, I would check the length first, then I go with `dict(zip(reversed(x), reversed(y)))`. There is no need to built an temporary list in between.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary yes that should be the preferred route! Thanks for the vote!